# glDrawPixels vs textures to draw a 2d buffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have a 2d graphic library that I want to use in OpenGL, to be able to mix 2d and 3d graphic. The simplest way seems to be with glDrawPixels, but many recent tutorial, and forums, suggest to use a texture with the command glTexSubImage2D, and then to draw a square with such a texture.

My question is: why? where is the advantage? It just adds one more step (memory buffer->texture->video buffer, instead of memory buffer->video buffer).

Comment: glDrawPixels is known to be very slow.

Comment: slower than glTexSubImage2D? Both commands do the same thing: copying from system memory to video memory.

Comment: Is the 2D textured interleaved in the 3D graphics or something? If it is always on top or bottom you might just blit it to the backbuffer using the window system directly.

Comment: my idea is to use 2d on top, with alpha channel, to draw score, or a HUD, or a simple GUI. I want to use wgl in windows, and glx in linux to create the context. What is the best way to blit the 2d image, with them? I was thinking of using overlays... but it looks like most graphic cards don't support them

Answer (score 3):

There are two main reasons:

- `glDrawPixels()` is deprecated, and not available in the OpenGL core profile, or in OpenGL ES.
- When drawing the image multiple times, a lot of repeated work can be saved by storing the image data in a texture.

It's quite rare that you would have to draw an image only once. Much more commonly, you'll draw it repeatedly, on each redraw. With `glDrawPixels()` you have to pass the image data into OpenGL each time. If you store it in a texture, you can draw it repeatedly, and OpenGL can reuse the same data each time.

To draw the content of a texture, you don't necessarily have to set up a shader, draw a quad, etc. You can use `glBlitFramebuffer()` to copy the texture content to the display.

Comment: It might be deprecated... but replacing it with a quad won't help, because commands to draw a quad (glOrtho , glLoadIdentity and so on) are deprecated, too, and not available on GLES2, so I would still need a different renderer (that would not work on version 1... and many computers still support only version 1)

Comment: Also, I do not want to use the same data at each redraw, because the buffer might have been changed and the screen needs to be updated, so I still need to send data to video card.

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenGL use a video memory, use a simple "draw pixel" must be really slow because you will do a lot GPU/CPU synchronisation for each draw.

When you use glTexSubImage2D, you ensure that your image will reside(all the time) into the video memory which is fast.

One way to load a texture inside video memory could be :

```
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &texture->mId);

glTextureParameteri(mId, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTextureParameteri(mId, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

GLsizei numMipmaps = ((GLsizei)log2(std::max(surface->w, surface->h)) + 1);
glTextureStorage2D(*texture, numMipmaps, internalFormat, surface->w, surface->h);
glTextureSubImage2D(*texture, 0, 0, 0, surface->w, surface->h,
                    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);

glGenerateTextureMipmap(*texture);
```

Don't forget binding if you do not want to use direct state access.

However, if you still want to perform pixel draw (for example for procedural rendering), you must write your own fragment shader to be as fast as possible

Comment: But even glTexSubImage2D transfers data to video memory, and if it used at each frame should do a lot of synchronisation. If the picture were static, I could just use it once to leave a copy in the video memory, but it is not static (and the 2d image is not rendered by Opengl, so no FBO can be used)

Comment: If the texture is not static, I guess there is several ways to achieve that. The first one is to load all image possible(a gif is componed with several images), the second is to use a persistent mapping with one PBO for example?

Comment: The texture is generated on the fly by the CPU, so it cannot be pre-loaded (it's the output of a 2d library). Neither can be generated directly on the GPU  (the 2d library works on a regular memory buffer)

Comment: So did you try to use PBO?

Comment: I haven't tried... are they supported on older OpenGl version, like 1.4 (I want my code to run everywhere, if possible)

Comment: I don't know when they are supported, but you have to know that it is the purpose of newest version of OpenGL to reduce the cost to work in both CPU and GPU side. And that's exactly what you want to do ^^. In all cases use glDrawPixels or send value via glTexImage2D will be slow if you don't want to use "correct way" ^^

Comment: Looks like they are supported since opengl 2.0, or gles 3.0. But some windows version still provide support only to version 1.4... sometimes, there is just a direct3d wrapper that support only version 1.1. And if I have to provide some fallback, I'd loose all speed gains